# How to run workmanager immediately

Tags: android

In my android app i have a functionality by which a user can sync  data      (saved in sqlite) by pressing Sync button some where in Drawer menu. On click  of sync button i starts the service and data gets synced to server.

But now i am using work manager to sync data. My question is how can we start work manager immediately on a button click.

I am creating Onetime request. some time it triggers but not other times.

Comment: You can use a background service instead of Workmanager

Comment: @HarishJose i can not use service. Because i also want to run sync process every 20 min (even if app is in background) . if i use service than i will have to make it a foreground service for updated android version (api 26 or above).

Comment: Yeah you're right. So why don't you try Workmanager with very less time(say schedule to few seconds from now)?

Comment: @HarishJose we can not set Workmanager to run less than 15 min

Answer (score 10):

WorkManager 2.7.0 introduces the concept of expedited work. Expedited work starts immediately and complete within a few minutes. here the [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#expedited)

```
OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<T>().apply {
    setInputData(inputData) 
 setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
}.build()
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running) and [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d) are "advanced" WorkManager guide/ medium post which goes over this.

In July 2020, Ben Weiss (Android Developer Relations at Google) [said](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d)

> We **recommend** you use WorkManager to execute long running immediate tasks.
> /
> Just make sure to make it a foreground service by using `setForeground`/ `setForegroundAsync`.

> This specifies that the WorkRequest is long-running or otherwise important. In this case, WorkManager provides a signal to the OS that the process should be kept alive if possible while this work is executing.

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#setForegroundAsync(androidx.work.ForegroundInfo))

> Calls to setForegroundAsync *must* complete before a ListenableWorker
> signals completion by returning a ListenableWorker.Result.
>
> **Under the hood, WorkManager manages and runs a foreground service** on
> your behalf to execute this WorkRequest, showing the notification
> provided in ForegroundInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Upd: 
The right way is to separate your logic from worker and call it from worker or from UI as needed. As Nurseyit pointed WM is not for immediate tasks. Also there is `RxWorker` from `android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx` [see docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work?hl=ru.#declaring_dependencies) which can easily wrap Rx network request or facade.

This can be used as quickfix or coding experiment:
You can cancel enqueued Work by button and enqueue it again next line. Work Manager will try to launch this new Worker as soon as possible. While button is pressed app is foreground so there is a good chance that Work will run immediately. This way also will not clutter Worker's by extracting task logic to separate class, checking that in-Worker task instance is not running, cancelling, waiting for immediate task, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation says that workManager is just for deferrable tasks. So we can't expect from it immediate execution. Maybe in some cases it will run immediately but there is no guaranty that it will do always. You should use coroutines or executors.

here is the answers:

[can I always use WorkManager instead of coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464190/can-i-always-use-workmanager-instead-of-coroutines)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe_yqM16hPQ

Comment: if you need to process every 20 minutes or at a fixed point of time, try to use alarm manager