# Can I always use WorkManager instead of coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Why should I bother with rx or coroutines when there is brilliant solution as WorkManager?

But for almost all tutorials, they use coroutines, so may be WorkManager has disadvantages?

Comment: Coroutines and `WorkManager` exist to solve different problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scope of both is different. WorkManager is to schedule deferrable (for any later time) or immediately.
tasks asynchronously.

> As documentation says
>
> The WorkManager API makes it easy to specify deferrable, asynchronous
>   tasks and when they should run. These APIs let you create a task and
>   hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate
>   time.

On the other hand, coroutines are designed to compute a given task only immediately and asynchronously.

Also
Internally, coroutines and WorkManager work differently. Work manager heavily depends on Android system components like Services, Alarm manager, etc to schedule the work whereas coroutines schedule the work on Worker Threads and also is a language feature unlike WorkManager (API). So it is safe to say that coroutines do not go beyond your application. On the other hand, WorkManager can even execute the given tasks when your application is not active. for instance, background services.

Also as Marko answered, using coroutines will lead to better code readability and quality due to their fundamental design.
I would also like to include [ANKO](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), Its a great library that provides a helpful API around coroutines for Android.

Comment: So when I combine those two it should work excellent, am I right? Because I get the readability of coroutines and the background execution of WorkManager?

Comment: In my opinion, you as a developer should choose platform native way to do the task, leverage the maximum platform's API offers you as all APIs are tightly aligned to each other by Android developers. It usually increase learning curve and many developers prefer to pick up already familiar instruments

Answer (score 11):

**Background tasks fall into one of the following main categories:**

1. Immediate
2. Deferred
3. Exact

To categorize a task, answer the following questions:

**Does the task need to complete while the user is interacting with the application?**

> If so, this task should be categorized for immediate execution. If
> not, proceed to the second question.

**Does the task need to run at an exact time?**

> If you do need to run a task at an exact time, categorize the task as
> exact.

Most tasks don't need to be run at an exact time. Tasks generally allow for slight variations in when they run that are based on conditions such as network availability and remaining battery. Tasks that don't need to be run at an exact time should be categorized as deferred.

Use Kotlin `Coroutine` when a task needs to execute immediately and if the task will end when the user leaves a certain scope or finishes an interaction.

Use `WorkManager` when a task needs to execute immediately and need continued processing, even if the user puts the application in the background or the device restarts

Use `AlarmManager` when a task that needs to be executed at an exact point in time

For more details, visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/)

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is writing clean code without explicitly constructed callbacks you pass to background tasks, then you'll find that coroutines are the only option.

Using coroutines by no means precludes using WorkManager or any other tool for background operations of your choosing. You can adapt the coroutines to any API that provides callbacks as a means to continue the execution with the results of background operations.

Answer (score 3):

From [official Documentation:](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#other-APIs)

> It is important to note that coroutines is a concurrency framework, whereas WorkManager is a library for persistent work.

Answer (score 2):

WorkManager:

Support for both asynchronous one-off and periodic tasks
Support for constraints such as network conditions, storage space, and charging status
Chaining of complex work requests, including running work in parallel
Output from one work request used as input for the next
Handles API level compatibility back to API level 14(see note)
Works with or without Google Play services
Follows system health best practices
LiveData support to easily display work request state in UI
Waits proper time to run.

Coroutines:

Clean code, works under the hood in a different way. Run immediately.

So depending on your requirements choose the better option.

Comment: Copy pasting the documentation is not really that useful. Maybe give your input and then link it as a reference :) -- You never know when this documentation changes and this generic text becomes outdated

Answer (score 1):

Has others replied, WorkManager solves a different problem than Kotlin's corountines or a reactive library like RxJava.

WorkManager is now available as beta and additional documentation is produced that hopefully makes this clear.
One of these documents is the blog post I worte with some colleagues: [Introducing WorkManager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712), where you can read:

> A common confusion about WorkManager is that it’s for tasks that needs to be run in a “background” thread but don’t need to survive process death. This is not the case. There are other solutions for this use case like Kotlin’s coroutines, ThreadPools, or libraries like RxJava. You can find more information about this use case in the [guide to background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/).